# SVG shape that expands to the right

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to create a ship shape (as seen from the top) in SVG, where I want the bow to always have the same aspect ratio, and the rest of the ship to grow and shrink with the HTML container.

A bit like the following:

[image]

Can I do that in pure SVG and possibly CSS (no Javascript involved)?

Edit:

In response so the answer given by @paul-lebeau, I want to avoid splitting the SVG up into two parts as well, as that doesn't seem to work reliably. Sometimes, a tiny space appears between the two parts, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: You can't really no, without javascript if you made the whole shape wider the bow will get wider too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot will depend on whether there is any other detail on the boat shape, or you  just need the outline.  If you just need the outline, then you can achieve the look you want using two SVG elements.  One element for the bow, and one for the body.

Note that in the three samples below, the three SVGs are identical apart from the class that sets the `width`.

```css
.short {
  width: 150px;
}

.medium {
  width: 250px;
}

.long {
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<svg height="50" class="short">
  <path d="M 70,0 L 70,50 A 70,25 0 1 1 70,0 Z"/>
  <rect x="70" y="0" width="100%" height="50"/>
</svg>

<br>

<svg height="50" class="medium">
  <path d="M 70,0 L 70,50 A 70,25 0 1 1 70,0 Z"/>
  <rect x="70" y="0" width="100%" height="50"/>
</svg>

<br>

<svg height="50" class="long">
  <path d="M 70,0 L 70,50 A 70,25 0 1 1 70,0 Z"/>
  <rect x="70" y="0" width="100%" height="50"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: The shapes are really basic, so that would work great. I actually tried that myself before posting this question, but it doesn't seem to work reliably. Sometimes a tiny space appears between the bow and the rest of the ship. I've updated my question to show you how your example looks like on my system (OSX+Chrome).

Comment: That shouldn't really be happening since I am using rounded pixel coordinates.  One workaround would be to overlap the shapes slightly. For example, try changing the `<rect>` to have `x="69"`.

Answer (score 0):

The SVG can also be used as a `background-image`. This variant uses a data URI, but it could also reference an external file. By using percentages, it can automatically scale to the HTML element it is applied to:

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='50'><path d='M 70,0 L 70,50 A 70,25 0 1 1 70,0 Z'/><rect x='70' y='0' width='100%' height='50'/></svg>");
}

.narrow {
  width: 150px;
}

.wide {
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="narrow"></div>
<div class="wide"></div>
```